# How to customize Zxing QR Scanner in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

Hello any idea on how to customize the zxing scanner in xamarin something like this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIjxw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom overlay.

There’s an example on the ZXing GitHub page here: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile#custom-overlays

Comment: Can I add a button in the overlay? Thanks for the response